# how to find descendant tag xpath from the list obtained from accordion group tag?

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

There is an accordion group, which has a tab list of locations. I could extract the list of locations, and click on each location.
But after I click on location, there are further accordion tab lists under that, which needs to be clicked to work with elements under that. I am unable to find x path for this sub-accordion group and its elements. 
Because the `div` id here is dynamic and using class name does not make any sense. 
Please guide me.

How I accessed accordion group for location:

```
List<WebElement> inVlist = driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//*[@id='invDtlXpath']/div/h4/a/span/span[1]"));
```

[how location tabs look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fTWnv.jpg)

**EDIT**:

adding the HTML code structure here, my question is how to access the terminal "i" component here, which is an icon to open the next accordion group.

```
+ <div id="invDtlXpath"
+ <div id="invDtlXpath"
- <div id="invDtlXpath"
  + <div id = "accordiongroup-4343-4558-tab" class="panel-heading"
  - <div id = "accordiongroup-4343-4558-panel" class="panel-collapse in collapse"
    - <div class="panel-body"
        - <div class="invDetails ng-scope"
                - <div class="ng-scope"
                   + <div class="site-zones"
           - <div class="inventory-opr-ctr">
            - <uib-accordion-class....
               - <div class=""
                - <div id=""
                   - <h4 class="panel-tite">
                    -<a class=""
                       -<span class=""</span>
                        -<i class="pull-right glyphicon ng-scope...
```

Comment: Add the html code not an image

Comment: Add the HTML DOM of the `accordion tablists` for which you want to create a `List`. Thanks